# How to concatenate string of consecutive numbers (in a range) in SQL with a loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

This question may have been answered, but, I might have a different problem to solve.

I have the following string: '123456' and the following range: `05 - 10`

How can I concatenate the string with each number in the range, so I have:
12345605
12345606
12345607
12345608
12345609
12345610

I will have a stored procedure that accepts 6 digits code, min and max numbers in the range. Then I will have to do some kind of processing of the data. It can be inserted later on or deleted or any sort of things.

This is what I will have in my stored procedure:

```
declare
    @firstSix varchar(6),
    @min varchar(2),
    @max varchar(2)

To do that I have started to write a loop:

WHILE(CAST(@min AS int) <= CAST(@max AS int)
BEGIN
     --here I will need to write a logic that concatenates the string. 
     SET @min = @min + 1
     SELECT @firstSix
END
```

So, using the following input 
`exec myProcedure '123456', '05', '10'` 
I will have, the following output:

```
12345605
12345606
12345607
12345608
12345609
12345610
```

or using the following input 
`exec myProcedure '123456', '15', '20'` 
I will have the following output:

```
12345615
12345616
12345617
12345618
12345619
12345620
```

I will, probably need to have a logic to determine if a value in the range has a leading zero or something

What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want recursive *CTE* :

```
with cte as (
     select @firstSix as firstSix , cast(@min as int) as mn, cast(@max as int) as mx
     union all
     select firstSix, mn + 1 , mx
     from cte
     where mn < mx
)
select concat(firstSix, right(concat('0', mn), 2))
from cte c;
```

By default is has `100` recursion level if you have a large suffix then query hint `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

**EDIT :** Using LOOP

```
DECLARE @table table (firstSix varchar(255))

WHILE(CAST(@min AS int) <= CAST(@max AS int))
BEGIN
     --here I will need to write a logic that concatenates the string. 
     INSERT INTO @table (firstSix)
         SELECT concat(@firstSix, right(concat('0', @min), 2))

     SET @min = @min + 1
END

SELECT firstSix
FROM @table;
```

Comment: Is that possible to do it with While loop? I understand that approach better?

Comment: @gene. . .  Yes it it possible with `loop` but you would need `DML`s in it. I meant you have to maintain one staging table in which all  `firstSix` will be stored & returned.

Comment: Thank you very much